# how to distribute pods to different projects

Tags: cocoapods, xcode-project, xcode-workspace

I have a workspace with 3 sub projects in it

each project depends on different pods, and there are pods that all projects depend on them

each project has at least 3 different targets, and several testing targets.

I want to define the pod file in such a way that the shared pods get installed on all projects,
and the ones that are not shared will be specific to each project, however i don't want to do

```
target :sometarget :exclusive=>true do

  xcodeproj 'project.xcodeproj'
  pod something
end
```

for every target, as there are at least 10 different targets in all the projects combined

how can i achieve my goal?